# Converting Django DeleteView to work with ajax

Tags: django, ajax, django-class-based-views

Im new to django and im stuck with an issue with ajax. I have the code below.

I have a django delte view. I want to use this with ajax. Right now the view is working but the CSRF Token doesnt  render.

I want to try and use a class based view as im new to learn. Im not sure why the CSRF TOKEN is not being rendered in the AJAX version. It appears when a browser is used but not when ajax is used.

Can someone please help ?

**view.py**

```
class DeleteOrderItemView(SuccessMessageMixin, generic.DeleteView):
    model = OrderItem
    template_name = 'pos/order_item_confirm_delte.html'

    # overwritten the delete to have a conformation code. Pending items do not need a conformation code.
    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("I was called !")
        self.object = self.get_object()
        conformation_code = self.request.POST.get('cancellation_code')

        if conformation_code == str(12345) or self.object.status == "Pending":
            # Record code and logged in user
            messages.success(self.request, "Order item {} deleted.".format(self.object.item.name))

            # print cancelled KOT

            return super(DeleteOrderItemView, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)

        else:
            messages.warning(self.request, "Incorrect conformation code.")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pos:delete_order_item', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk}))

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        order_pk = self.object.order.pk
        return reverse_lazy('pos:order_details', kwargs={'pk': order_pk})

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        """ Allow AJAX requests to be handled more gracefully """
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            context = self.get_context_data(**response_kwargs)
            rendered = render_to_string(self.template_name, context)

            return JsonResponse({'delete_form': rendered}, safe=False, **response_kwargs)
        else:
            return super(generic.DeleteView, self).render_to_response(context, **response_kwargs)
```

**Javascript**

```
/* Load the delete form */
$("#js_order_list_items").on("click", "#js_remove_item", function(){

    $("#modal-actions").modal("show");
    remove_url = $('#js_remove_item').attr('js_delete_url')

    $.ajax({
        url: remove_url,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#modal-actions").modal("show");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.delete_form)
         $("#modal-actions .modal-content").html(data.delete_form)
        }
    })
});
```

**HTML**

```
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
    <br/>
    <div class="col-12 alert alert-danger">
        <h4>Delete item for {{ orderitem.order.customer.name }}</h4>
      </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>{{ orderitem.item.name }}</strong></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Quantity: {{ orderitem.quantity }}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Price: {{ orderitem.price }}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Ordered by: {{ orderitem.order.user.username }}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                {% if messages %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                            {% for message in messages %}
                                {{ message }}
                            {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <hr/>
        <form method="POST" action="{% url 'pos:delete_order_item' pk=orderitem.pk %}" class="js_confirm_delete_form">

            {% csrf_token %}

            {% if orderitem.status == 'Confirmed' %}
                <label>Cancellation Code: </label>  <input type="password" id="cancellation_code" name="cancellation_code"><br/><hr/>
            {% endif %}
            <input type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-danger btn-large btn-lg">
            <a href="{% url 'pos:order_details' pk=orderitem.order.pk %}" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-large btn-lg" type="button">Cancel</button> </a>
        </form>

        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It looks like your question is missing code fragments (of the view, the html/ajax part, etc.)

Comment: I just put the code. sorry my first question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue my self. The render_to_string needs the request passed to it for the csrf_token to work.

```
rendered = render_to_string(self.template_name, context, request=self.request)
```